# wrong fs type, bad option with USB HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk, ext4

I am fairly new to Linux and wanted to take a USB powered HDD that I was using as storage on a Raspberry Pi and add it as a data drive on an Ubuntu 20.04 PC (I want to go from the Pi to this new machine as my media server and there is data on the drive I want to keep). I plugged in the new drive and all worked fine, there were 2 partitions, system boot and writeable. I removed the system boot partition as I was getting weird startup experiences (taking a ton of time). Now I have 269MB of free space and a nearly 8TB Ext4 partition when I look at disks. When I try to mount the partition, I get this

[image]

I have looked online at various forum posts about how I more than likely just need to move the superblock, but I am very nervous about losing data on the drive. Is there anything I can do here to mount the partition as is?

**Edit**

**Output of `sudo fsck /dev/sdb2`**

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 1953440849 blocks
The physical size of the device is 1953440768 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
```

**Output of `egrep 'c21fdada|sdb2' /etc/fstab`**

```
/dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=data 0 0
```

Comment: Yeah, you may be stuck with trying to find a good superblock. This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543227

Comment: Try using ext4 instead of auto in fstab, (if that's the actual filesystem). Something might be guessing the wrong fs.

Comment: @WayneVosberg I get below trying to change superblock

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
writable: recovering journal
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on writable


writable: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

writable: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

Comment: @ubfan1 same error

Answer (score 1):

Same issue when I switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. The hard disk did not mounted automatically because the helper to handle filesystem was (misteriously) missed during the switch between OS versions.

From Applications > Disks check the helper you need. See the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkEWE.png

In my case is NFTS. If it is not set properly you should see there something as 'Not Mounted'.

Then install the required helper. In my case was NFTS, so:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ntfs-3g
```

I hope it is helpfull for you.

Comment: OP clearly says they played with the partitions. They mess up the super block this is not an answer.

Comment: This saved my a*s though. +1